# Is making Shrine from Gold a sin?

Tags: islamic-philosophy, gold, shrine

I have been asked this questions many times, That why the zarih of Imam Hussain and Moula abbas (and many others) is made of Gold. Sometimes it is referenced that

> "Gold is forbidden(Haram) for men, and it should not be used this way,

and sometimes it is said

> that money with all this gold, could feed many needy people".

I am looking for a better logical answer. I know the ideology of Wahhabi school of thought(since they talk about razing prophet SAWW shrine [1](http://www.belfasttelegraph.co.uk/news/world-news/saudi-arabias-proposal-to-destroy-prophet-mohammeds-tomb-and-move-remains-to-anonymous-grave-risks-new-muslim-division-30557589.html) [2](https://defence.pk/pdf/threads/saudi-arabia-to-raze-prophet-mohammeds-tomb-to-build-larger-mosque.295338/) [3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Destruction_of_early_Islamic_heritage_sites_in_Saudi_Arabia)  ). Other than that any reasonable answer would be appreciated.

Comment: I think the issue is less about silver or gold but about building anything on a grave. So your inquiry is basically on something secindary.

Comment: With respect, I am in search for the reasons to make it with gold or silver, as this gold could be used more of better ways. I respect shrines, but expect a good answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The golden domes above the holy shrines of the Prophet and his Ahl-ul-Bait and other respected personalities in Islam are a sign of their value for the believer who visits them. These personalities gave everything they had for the cause of Islam and without their selfless effort and sacrifice we would not be able to call ourselves Muslim today.

The gold, silver, gemstones and other artwork which can be found in the shrines and outside shows the deep love, respect and appreciation people feel for these special personalities.

To express love and respect, we always use valuable items to do so. Therefore, the husband presents his beloved wife with jewellery if he can afford it.

One would think that the money being spent to build and maintain the shrines could be spent better elsewhere. But this is not the case. In fact the shrines are not being built by spending taxes which would then be not available for projects for the needy. Rather they are built by the money people give to the shrine. Each visitor leaves behind a relatively small amount of money, which adds up to a vast amount as  millions of people visit the shrines each year.

For example, here is a link about the shrine of [Ali](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hDv450gl0d8) ibn Abi Talib, where the money being given in charity to the shrine is counted every Friday by volunteers. This link is in Arabic.

Many charitable projects are being financed by the donations. Here are some examples of projects, the shrine of Hussain ibn Ali in Kerbala, Iraq has paid for:

- Drinking water project (Whole of Kerbala has now clean drinking
  water)
- agricultural [project](https://imamhussain.org/arabic/projects-3/18869/p://)
- [Hospital](https://imamhussain.org/arabic/inpictures-5/19413/), with state-of-the-art equipment, offering free treatment
- Kerbala airport
- Housing for refugees
- Military group to fight Daesh

and many more.

So the shrines are actually generating money rather than costing money.

The argument that gold is haram for men is not applicable here, as it only applies to wearing gold like rings etc.

Comment: Thank you very much, for such an elegant answer with perfect logic. The references for Projects are also remarkable.

Comment: This even clearly goes against the teachings of ahl-ul Bait: Abu'l-Hayyaj al-Asadi told that 'Ali (b. Abu Talib) said to him:
Should I not send you on the same mission as Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) sent me? Do not leave an image without obliterating it, or a high grave without levelling It. This hadith has been reported by Habib with the same chain of transmitters and he said: (Do not leave) a picture without obliterating it.

Comment: Shia school of thought doubts the authenticity of this hadith. If it were authentic then we would have to level the Prophet's grave as well.

Comment: Interesringly shrine's and mausoleums were not present in the early days of Islam and until the Abbasid dynasty became weak. As this basically goes against quran and sunnah. And personally i'd prefer the kaaba and the masjid an-Nabawi as authentic as it was as thar would at least keep and give a better insight to the histiry of these places.